# In my flutter app, i have 2 functions .. the second one debends on the first one but the problem is the second one executed before the first one

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

i tried async ,await but not working
and i tried then & whenCompleted but not working too ..

i do a function for uploading the images to firebase storage
and put the links in a list
[this is the first function source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DJ15.png)

here , i do this function for store the post with images links to firestore
[the second function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vx0DV.png)

finally i did this function to execute the second function after the first one finished
[third function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLdM5.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try making the calling function, i.e, `publishPost` as `void` instead of a `Future`. Also, remove the async and await keywords, because in case of `async-await`, both the functions, i.e, `uploadPostImages` and `uploadPost` run almost simultaneously. If you remove the `async-await`, it basically blocks the flow of the application, till `uploadPostImages` is completed. Then it proceeds to `uploadPosts`. Or you could do something like this:

```
void publishPost({<function-parameters>}) {
     uploadPostImages({<function-parameters>}).then((value) {
         uploadPost({<function-parameters>});
     }
     ...
}
```